# AVL tree in-order traversal is not working

Tags: java, traversal, avl-tree

My AVL tree is implemented in Java using a two-dimensional array of integers `avlTree[35][5]` - The columns represent:

- [0] - Height Left
- [1] - Left Child
- [2] - Data
- [3] - Right Child
- [4] - Height Right.

I am calling the following method from the main program, and as a result I get three nodes: the leftmost node twice followed by its parent.

```
public void inorderTraversal(int root) {
    if ((Main.avlTree[root][1] == 0) && (Main.avlTree[root][3] == 0)) {
        System.out.println(Main.avlTree[root][2]);
    } else {
        if (Main.avlTree[root][1] != 0) {
            root = Main.avlTree[root][1];
            inorderTraversal(root);
        }
        System.out.println(Main.avlTree[root][2]);

        if (Main.avlTree[root][3] != 0) {
            root = Main.avlTree[root][3];
            inorderTraversal(root);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i suppose this is a homework, but declare the method like  `inorderTraversal(**final** int root) ` and it will help solve the issue. as for the StackOverflowError - most likely you have a cycle in the tree.

Comment: You don't need to declare it final. The type is int therefore the "real" value is not changed.

Comment: @MasterCassim, root stands for the current index of the node, practically the node. the code (`root = ...`) alters that, hence it's screwed. The final was a tip since that's a homework. There is not "real" value but an index to a Node that's effectively altered.

Comment: yes; I see it now ; ) it problematic if the first and second if is executed in the else - case.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this test program:

```
public class AVLTree {

    /*
        [0] - Height Left
        [1] - Left Child
        [2] - Data
        [3] - Right Child
        [4] - Height Right.
    */
    private static int[][] avlTree;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        avlTree = new int[4][5];

        // root (L: 1; R: 3)
        avlTree[0][0] = 0;
        avlTree[0][1] = 1;
        avlTree[0][2] = 3005;
        avlTree[0][3] = 2;
        avlTree[0][4] = 1;

        // parent: root (L: -1; R: -1)
        avlTree[1][0] = 0;
        avlTree[1][1] = -1;
        avlTree[1][2] = 73375;
        avlTree[1][3] = -1;
        avlTree[1][4] = 0;

        // parent: root (L: 3; R: -1)
        avlTree[2][0] = 0;
        avlTree[2][1] = 3;
        avlTree[2][2] = 831954;
        avlTree[2][3] = -1;
        avlTree[2][4] = 0;

        // parent: 2 (L: -1; R: -1)
        avlTree[3][0] = 0;
        avlTree[3][1] = -1;
        avlTree[3][2] = 7485;
        avlTree[3][3] = -1;
        avlTree[3][4] = 0;

        inOrder(0);
    }

    private static void inOrder(int root) {
        if(root == -1) {
            // nothing to do
            return ;
        }

        // call function with left child
        inOrder( avlTree[root][1] );

        // print root
        System.out.println( avlTree[root][2]);

        // call function with right child
        inOrder( avlTree[root][3]);
    }
}
```

and the output is as expected:

> 73375
>   3005
>   7485
>   831954

I have no problem with your code either; it works fine in my test. Maybe your tree is false? I would also suggest using -1 as the right / left child if there is none; otherwise it's a bit misleading because 0 could mean the node at positon 0.